# Listen for changes in CallLog.Calls

Tags: android, android-contentprovider

I'm building an app that listen for changes in the CallLog.Calls content provider. So any changes on this content provider will notify the the app's observer, that will insert the data has changed.

But there is a problem, the app is notified when its not running, ie, the app will not capture the data has changed while not running.

So my question is, is there a way to capture the data that changed while the app was not running? So, example, I made 8 calls, and the app was not running, so 8 new data has been added to the CallLog.calls content provider. So is there a way to capture this 8 new data once the application starts?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is an `Intent` that is fired on an incoming call you could get your app to respond by using a `BroadcastReceiver` and create an `IntentFilter` in your manifest.

Or just query the provider when your app launches...

Edit:

`ACTION_PHONE_STATE_CHANGED` is a `TelephonyManager` intent you can listen for and check if it is `TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING`.

Comment: In fact I have an ContentObserver that is fired on an incoming or outgoing call. But the app only listen for the notify when its running. When its not running it doesn't listen, so the calls I've made are missed by the app, ie, the app don't capture the data. Got it? So I ḿ looking for a solution that may check or listen once the app runs. I was trying to query the size of the provider, declaring two variables, one with the last size of the provider, and other with the current size, so, once I run the app, I compare both. Is it a good solution?

Comment: if there is no incoming call Intent that you can respond to then checking if the call database has new rows seems perfectly acceptable to me.

i am sure there is an incoming call Intent though.  if you have a receiver registered in the app manifest with an intent filter specifying that intent your app will fire up.  probably best to get your app to fire up a service to handle it in the background though.

check the Intent class and TelephonyManager class to see if there is an intent.

Comment: I think I have to implement a Service.

Comment: that would be best.  are you familiar with broadcastreceivers and adding the intentfilter in the manifest.xml.  it's all explained in the sdk docs.  let me know if i can be of anymore help.  all the best.